# Как оптимально реализовать поиск массива в списке массивов и вернуть его позицию?

Tags: java, массивы, поиск, arraylist, indexof

Есть целочисленный массив 
`array = { 0, 5, 10, 0, 11, 14, 13, 4, 11, 8, 8, 7, 1, 4, 12, 11 }`

Есть некий список массивов (несортированных), сейчас это LinkedHashSet (т.к. важна последовательность добавления элементов), в который я добавляю массивы, конвертированные в строки. На каждой итерации происходит проверка, существует ли такой массив в списке и если да, то возвращаю его индекс. А именно:

```
Set<String> arrayList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
arrayList.add(Arrays.toString(array));
while (true)
{
   ...
   arrayString = Arrays.toString(array);
   if (arrayList.contains(arrayString)) {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList);
      int firstEntryIndex = list.indexOf(arrayString);
      ...
   }
   arrayList.add(arrayString);
}
```

Требуется избавиться от contains и, возможно, лишних преобразований, оптимизировав время выполнения кода.

Comment: а вам зачем это все? По тому коду, что есть, создавать каждый раз список, чтобы из него получать индекс - расточительно, можно заменить set на map, и хранить индекс как значение. Если по индексу просто из какого-то списка достается массив, можно и сам массив хранить.

Comment: Это нужно, чтобы получить число итераций, когда массив в списке  повторится (совпадет с имеющимся).